# SQL - Update multiple fields per row from the same lookup table without multiple joins

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a temp table similar to this

```
create table #temp
(
    log_id int,
    ...some other fields,
    one_user_id int,
    two_user_id int,
    three_user_id int,
    four_user_id int,
    one_username varchar(50),
    two_username varchar(50),
    three_username varchar(50),
    four_username varchar(50)
)
```

I start out knowing all the user ids, but then I need to look up their names in a user lookup table and update the name fields in the temp table.

```
create table #user_lookup
(
    user_id int,
    username varchar(50)
)
```

I know I could join to the user lookup table once for every id using a different alias to get them all, but I was looking for a slick way to do it just once.

Any ideas ?

EDIT:

Ok, more info on the purpose for multiple users per row. The #temp table row (not all fields displayed) signifies a log entry that represents a collation of multiple actions by potentially multiple users, but all tying to that one log row.

I could have duplicate log rows, one for each user who played a role, but it's easier to consume on the client side as single rows.

This is why there are multiple users per row.

Comment: You need to either `JOIN` multiple times or fix your table design.

Comment: i said i know i could join multiple times and i was looking for an alternative

Comment: @Ian: JNK's point is that there is no alternative without redesigning your `#temp` table structure.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli - You are correct.  With the current (flawed) design multiple `JOIN`s are how you have to do it.

Comment: What would the suggested design change be, assuming it would still allow for multiple users per row ?

Comment: @Ian - what's the point of having four per row?  Is there a logical connection?  Best way would be a denormalized table. More info on your purpose and we can give you a design

Comment: @Ian: I have offered the only alternative I can think of, but it'd be silly not to use `JOIN`'s when they are the simplest solution and serve the purpose quite well.  Not wanting to use `JOIN`'s because you don't want to use `JOIN`'s is not a sensible reason.

Comment: @mellamokb: i was simply asking if there was a slick alternative that i was unaware of. i wasn't trying to be obtuse.

Comment: @Ian: OK.  Then the answer in practical terms is no, there is no alternative :-).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
UPDATE temp
   SET one_username = u1.username
     , two_username = u2.username
     , three_username = u3.username
     , four_username = u4.username
  FROM #temp as temp
  join #user_lookup as u1 on u1.user_id = temp.one_user_id
  join #user_lookup as u2 on u2.user_id = temp.two_user_id
  join #user_lookup as u3 on u3.user_id = temp.three_user_id
  join #user_lookup as u4 on u4.user_id = temp.four_user_id
```

But I don't know why you have four users in one table... ;)

Comment: this is how i'm currently doing it. i was just wondering if there was another way that i wasn't familiar with. thx for the feedback though :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were running four updates. So if you are making four joins the alternative is make four individual updates. I think four individuals updates is better since the code more readable.
(Only Chuck Norris can write readable SQL)

Answer (score 0):

The only other real alternative solution is to pull in the related records with an `IN` clause and make use of `CASE` statements to tie the usernames with the correct user_id's.  However this is way more complicated than simply using a `JOIN` statement and doesn't really offer any advantage except that there aren't multiple `JOIN`'s involved.  Here is a complete working sample of how to pull data using this structure:

```
create table #temp
(
    one_user_id int,
    two_user_id int,
    three_user_id int,
    four_user_id int,
    one_username varchar(50),
    two_username varchar(50),
    three_username varchar(50),
    four_username varchar(50)
)
insert #temp (one_user_id, two_user_id, three_user_id, four_user_id) values (1, 3, 6, 7)
insert #temp (one_user_id, two_user_id, three_user_id, four_user_id) values (2, 5, 8, 1)

;with User_Lookup as (
    select 1 as user_id, 'abc' as username union
    select 2, 'def' union
    select 3, 'ghi' union
    select 4, 'jkl' union
    select 5, 'mno' union
    select 6, 'pqr' union
    select 7, 'stu' union
    select 8, 'vwx' union
    select 9, 'jon' union
    select 10, 'bob'
), Result as (
    select
        one_user_id,
        two_user_id,
        three_user_id,
        four_user_id,
        max(case when U.user_id = one_user_id then U.username end) as one_username,
        max(case when U.user_id = two_user_id then U.username end) as two_username,
        max(case when U.user_id = three_user_id then U.username end) as three_username,
        max(case when U.user_id = four_user_id then U.username end) as four_username
    from
        #Temp T,
        User_Lookup U
    where
        U.user_id in (T.one_user_id, T.two_user_id, T.three_user_id, T.four_user_id)
    group by
        T.one_user_id, T.two_user_id, T.three_user_id, T.four_user_id
)
update
    #temp
set
    one_username = R.one_username,
    two_username = R.two_username,
    three_username = R.three_username,
    four_username = R.four_username
from
    Result R
inner join
    #temp T on R.one_user_id=T.one_user_id and R.two_user_id=T.two_user_id
        and R.three_user_id=T.three_user_id and R.four_user_id=T.four_user_id

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Output:

```
one_user_id two_user_id three_user_id   four_user_id    one_username    two_username    three_username  four_username
1           3           6               7               abc             ghi             pqr             stu
2           5           8               1               def             mno             vwx             abc
```